# Is storing a firebase auth token in the browser cookies safe to do?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-chrome-extension, firebase-authentication

Working on a side-project of mine right now where after the user signs into the website/user-dashboard (via firebase auth) – I want the user to be automatically logged into the chrome extension that pairs with the website. Is it safe to store the auth token in the browser cookies when the user signs in and then access that cookie from the extension to seamlessy log them in to the extension as well? Or should I use the browser api to send a message (when user logs in) from the website to the extension containing the auth token? I plan to verify the token the extension recieves via firebase-admin. Is there a better way to do this im unaware of? Thanks in advance!

Haven't implemented anything yet besides the login on the website. Wanted to see the security risks of the previously mentioned methods before writing any code.